# How to obtain spring beans in activiti behavior?

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I am working on workflow based project which is using activiti. while doing proof of concept I came across two ways to provide implementation for service task.

1. **Java delegate**:: where we give the implementation for a particular task in activiti and the flow progresses based on the flow defined in BPMN diagram.
2. **Activiti behavior**::where we can control the flow by specifying the transition to follow

In the first method I am able to obtained the spring beans using auto wiring from spring context however in the second one I am not able to auto wire.

I have searched for this in **Activiti in Action guide and Alfresco community** but was not able to obtain any answers on this

Also it would be great if anyone could tell about the tradeoff between the two .

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @luboskrnac Thank you very much for reply . I tried using both interfaces mentioned above . In java delegate case i was able to obtain the bean from the spring context however in activiti behavior i was not able to obtain the bean from spring context. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Sorry, nobody will help you if we wouldn't see your code.